# Display a text field after a checkbox is checked in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a requirement in which a Text field has to be made editable or rendered when a check box is checked, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a strictly Visualforce code sample that will work as well:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!theSObject.CheckBox__c}">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="theBlock"/>
   </apex:inputCheckbox>

   <apex:inputText value="{!theSObject.TextField__c}" disabled="false" rendered="{!(theSObject.CheckBox__c == true)}"/>
   <apex:inputText value="{!theSObject.TextField__c}" disabled="true" rendered="{!(theSObject.CheckBox__c != true)}"/>

   <!-- Or to simply have a field that appears only when the box is checked -->
   <apex:inputText value="{!theSObject.TextField__c}" rendered="{!(theSObject.CheckBox__c == true)}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

In addition to this, you can add an action in the action support if you wish to do further processing in Apex, like this:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myMethod}" rerender="theBlock"/>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: The actionSupport event for a checkbox should be onclick, onchange is not reliable across all browsers.

Comment: I often forget that people still use IE ;) Thanks Jordy - good catch.

Comment: what if the checkbox field is not an object field. then how will i do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to toggle the disabled attribute of the text input element. Below is a sample page showing how, note, there are a few oddities in here.

First, if you disable the field initially using `disabled="true"` on the `<apex:inputText>` then even if you enable it, values entered will **not** be sent back to the controller, hence disabling the field on load with javascript. I believe this is to prevent any chance of updating a field's value when the developer has specified that it should be disabled.

The second odd point is that even though you set `element.disabled` to "disabeld" to disable an element, to check whether it is disabled you have to treat it as a boolean value!

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ToggleInput(theId)
            {
                var e = document.getElementById(theId);

                if(e != null)
                {
                    e.disabled = (e.disabled ? false : "disabled");
                }
            }

            window.onload = function () { document.getElementById('{!$Component.textInput}').disabled = "disabled"; }

        </script>
        <apex:inputCheckbox onchange="ToggleInput('{!$Component.textInput}');" value="{!Contact.Some_Checkbox__c}"/>
        <apex:inputText id="textInput" value="{!Contact.Some_Text_Field__c}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Update"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

To do all this without javascript, I imagine you'd set the `<apex:inputText>`'s disabled attribute based on the value of the checkbox field, then use an `<apex:actionSupport>` tag to fire an action when the checkbox changes and specify the id of the `<apex:inputText>` in the `rerender` attribute. You'd also have to wrap it in an `<apex:actionRegion>` to prevent other fields being sent and causing validation errors if required fields aren't filled etc.. This also means you have to wait for a request to change the state of the text field, so the javascript is the best route for speed.